Не отправляет видео aiogram 3 как исправить?
Код:
@hand_router.message(CommandStart())
async def start(message: Message):
    start_video = FSInputFile('start.MP4') 
    await message.answer_video(start_video, caption='<b>Привет! </b>\n'
        '<b>Хочешь научиться запускать рекламу в Telegram за 3 бесплатных урока?</b>\n\n'
        '<b>Меня зовут Иван Скробов, я в маркетинге с 2013 года, запустил более 1000 рекламных кампаний и имею 100+ успешных кейсов. Специально для тебя записал курс по запуску рекламы в Telegram через сервис МТС-Маркетолог.</b>\n\n'
        '<b>В этом курсе я покажу:</b>\n'
        '✅ Регистрация и обзор личного кабинета МТС-Маркетолог.\n'
        '✅ Сбор Telegram-каналов, в которых есть целевая аудитория.\n'
        '✅ Запуск таргетированной рекламы в Telegram по интересам.\n'
        '✅ Запуск таргетированной рекламы в Telegram-каналах.\n\n'
        '<b> Начало диалога регистрирует тебя на бесплатный марафон по запуску рекламы в Telegram </b>\n'
        '<b>Ты научишься запускать рекламу своими руками без помощи специалистов за 3 бесплатных урока. Через 30 секунд тут появится первый урок.</b>',
        parse_mode='HTML'
    )

выдаёт ошибку
aiogram.exceptions. TelegramNetworkError: HTTP Client says Client OSError: [Errno 2] Can not write request body for https://api. telegram.org/bot7795404184: AAE Ir-rewQB8pORYe1558N1GUR_2nnphzSY/sendVideo


Может видео слишком большое? ‍♀️Есть ограничение в 50мб для прямой загрузки файлов через бота. Вполне возможно это распространяется и на видео. Тут либо подымать своё АПИ для обхода ограничения, либо вручную загружать файлы, а уже потом использовать  их id для отправки. Тут обсуждали.

У меня video_id на сервере слетает не удобно
